# UIImageView spawning on other UIImageViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, collision

I have an app where a user drives a car and collects coins. I have an array with all the bombs in it that the user tries to avoid. Basically, the problem is that when I spawn the coins, they often land on bombs, making the game impossible. So, I wrote the following code to prevent this, but coins still spawn on bombs (note that these are all uiimageviews). Here is my code:

```
UIImageView *one = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"goldCoin.png"]];
CGRect rectOne = CGRectMake(arc4random() % (900), arc4random() % (700), 40, 40);

BOOL coinSpawned = false;

while (coinSpawned == false) {

    rectOne = CGRectMake(arc4random() % (900), arc4random() % (700), 40, 40);

    coinSpawned = true;

    for (UIImageView *two in bombArray) {

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(rectOne,two.frame)) {

            coinSpawned = false;

        }
    }
}

[one setFrame:rectOne];
[self.view addSubview:one];
levelCount = levelCount + 1;

coinFrame = one.frame;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(coinIntersection:)
                               userInfo:one
                                repeats:YES];
```

Further note that *two are the uiimageviews in the array bombArray and coinFrame is a global variable that I don't really use.Also, levelcount is something I use later, but is irrelevant for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Maybe this is just a copy-and-paste issue, but it looks like your logic for setting the coin's frame is actually inside of your while loop, so it executes regardless of the value of `coinSpawned`. You might not have noticed this because your indents are off. Try closing the while loop right after the for loop and see if that changes anything.</strike>

**EDIT:** Just realized the indents are actually off within the for loop, and your braces do appear to be correct. There are a number of other factors that might be involved here. Are your bombs' frames ever changing, and you're not accounting for the change? Are the bombs hierarchical siblings of the coins (if they are in different superviews, the coordinate systems may be different)?

*Also, just an aside: why are you using `true` and `false` instead of `YES` and `NO`? This probably doesn't have to do with your problem, but it's very non-standard.*